# Hide Terms of Use Prompt when using Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

I've developed an Android App that uses Chrome Custom Tabs and my app is used for Check in Check out scenario where a new user has to Login and Logout in every 2 hours.

Therefore every time they login, Chrome presents a Prompt to accept Terms of Use - "Welcome to Chrome".

Also it presents a prompt for "Turn on Sync?"

**Is there a way to prevent showing this?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems the user has to login / logout from the entire device, not only to your app. Can you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: The user never login to the device because its used for Check in Check out scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad privacy practices to auto-consent your users to Terms that they could not even read, even if the flow seems better, don't do that.